# C++: problems with indicator, wsk

Tags: c++, object, codeblocks, objective-c++, indicator

I have some problem with my code, beacuse I'm not very good in this staff but I have to write this on my projekt.

**Pracownicy.h**

```
class Pracownicy
{

private:
    char Imie[30];
    char Nazwisko[30];
    int Numer_pracownika;

public:
    Pracownicy();
    int ilosc_pracownikow;
    void dodaj_pracownika();
    void usun_pracownika();
    void wyswietl_wszystkich();
    void wyswietl_pracownika();
};

extern wsk = new Pracownicy[ilosc_pracownikow];
```

**Pracownicy.cpp**

```
#include "Pracownicy.h"

using namespace std;

Pracownicy::Pracownicy()
    : ilosc_pracownikow(1)
{

}

void Pracownicy::dodaj_pracownika()
{

    wsk = new Pracownicy[ilosc_pracownikow);
    Pracownicy User;

    cout<<"\nDodawanie nowego pracownika."<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Imie: ";
    cin>>wsk -> Imie[i];
    cout<<"Nazwisko: ";
    cin>>wsk -> Nazwisko[i];
    cout<<"Podaj numer od 00 do 99: ";
    cin>>wsk -> Numer_pracownika[i];
     for (wsk->NumerPracownika[i] = 0; wsk->NumerPracownika[i <=ilosc_pracownika]; i++ )
        {
            for (wsk->NumerPracownika[j] = 0; wsk->NumerPracownika[j <=ilosc_pracownika]; j++ )
            {
                while (wsk->Numer_pracownika[i] == wsk->Numer_pracownika[j])
                {
                    cout<<"\n------------------------------------------"<<endl;
                    cout<<"Numer pracownika juz istnieje w bazie."<<endl<<endl;
                    cout<<"Podaj nowy numer: ";
                    cin>>wsk -> Numer_pracownika[i];
                }
            }
        }

    cout<<"Pracownik zostal zapisany."<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"------------------------------------------"<<endl;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Pracownicy.h"

using namespace std;
int wybor;

Pracownicy::Pracownicy()
    : ilosc_pracownikow(0)
{

}

int main()
{
Pracownicy pracownicy;
    for(;;)
 {
    cout<<"\nMENU ZEGARA"<<endl;
    cout<<"------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"1 -> Dodanie nowego pracownika"<<endl;
    cout<<"2 -> Usuniecie pracownika"<<endl;
    cout<<"3 -> Wyswietlenie pracownikow"<<endl;
    cout<<"4 -> Zamkniecie zegara"<<endl;
    cout<<"------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Podaj co chcesz wykonac: ";
    cin>>wybor;
    cout<<"------------------------------------------"<<endl;

    switch(wybor)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            wsk->dodaj_pracownika();

            cout<<"Chcesz dodac nowgo pracownika?"<<endl;
            cout<<"Dla TAK wpisz 1"<<endl;
            cout<<"Dla NIE wpisz 0"<<endl;
            cout<<"------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            cin>>wybor;

            while(wybor == 1)
            {
            wsk->dodaj_pracownika();
            cout<<"Chcesz dodac nowgo pracownika?"<<endl;
            cout<<"Dla TAK wpisz 1"<<endl;
            cout<<"Dla NIE wpisz 0"<<endl;
            cout<<"------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            cin>>wybor;
            }
        }
    break;
```

First problem is in **Pracownicy.h** *error: 'wsk' does not name a type*

Second is in **Main.cpp** *error: 'wsk' was not declared in this scope*

Maybe you can help, I know that sometimes it is really small problem but I didn't see that. Or you can give me some advice about this code.

And I'm really sory but as you can see I'm not English and my language can be terrible.

Comment: `extern wsk = new Pracownicy[ilosc_pracownikow];` I'm guessing `wsk` is the name of your pointer. Where do you declare it's type?

Comment: nowhere? but I don't know how I must declare this... because when I try it always have some errors...

Comment: `Pracownicy[ilosc_pracownikow);` should be `Pracownicy(ilosc_pracownikow);`. Also, you're passing `ilosc_pracownikow` into `Pracownicy` even though the constructor doesn't take any paramaters.

Comment: As for your second issue, you declared `wsk` in `Pracownicy::dodaj_pracownika()`, which is not accessible by `main`

Comment: You should have two classes `Pracownik` and `Pracownicy` (eng: employee, employees)  - do not put functionalities of two classes into one. Then your `Pracownicy` shall have array (or better vector) of Pracownik class. Then You won't need those `extern`global variable

Comment: Jasse J -> thank you... it's working now... i really didn't see that...

Comment: PiotrNycz -> I used vector before and it was worked really well but my Profesor said that I can't use this... so I try write something....